# Fix: Stale element reference in python loop

Tags: python, selenium, loops

There are 100 items in the `persons` list and I want to loop through each of them and click them excluding the previously clicked link.

```
d = 0
persons = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='i-edit mrs no-text-decoration ember-view']")

for i, person in zip(names[int(d):], persons[int(d):]):    
    person.click()
    time.sleep(1.2)
    fill_in_activate = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-default']") # add a 2nd input field
    for btn in fill_in_activate[1:]: #skips the first element it finds
        btn.click() # clicks the 2nd field
           
    # Select and fill out input field
    fill_in = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='form-control ember-view ember-text-field']") 
    first = True
    for field1 in fill_in[3:]: # selecting 4th field
        if first:
            first = False
            field1.send_keys(f'{i[0]}') # fill out information
        else:
            field1.send_keys(f'{i[1]}') # fill out information
    
    # step to save out input into the site        
    save = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-success']").click() # Saves all inputs      
    time.sleep(2)

    browser.execute_script("window.history.go(-2)")     #browser.back() # goes back to the previous page
    d += 1 # auto-increments d
    time.sleep(5)
    persons = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='i-edit mrs no-text-decoration ember-view']")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what this page is nor do I know exactly what happens when you click on a `person`. But it seems fairly clear that the clicking causes a page, probably the same page, to  be reloaded and thus rendering the remaining `persons` stale. So, you need to re-fetch the `persons` elements *each time through the loop*. To the extent that my assumption is correct, then following is a general outline. You may need other adjustments in the code since I am not doing an initial `zip`:

```
d = 0
while True:
    persons = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='i-edit mrs no-text-decoration ember-view']")
    if d >= len(persons):
        break
    i = names[d]
    person = persons[d]
    person.click()
    ... # rest of logic
    # end of loop
    d += 1
```